# C# casting generic of T

Tags: c#, generics

I have the following method:

```
 private void SaveCatalog<T>(T data)
        {
            // Open database (or create if doesn't exist)
            using (var db = new LiteDatabase(@"database.db"))
            {
                string tableName = null;

                switch (cboCatalogs.Text.ToLower())
                {
                    case "area":
                        tableName = "setup_area";

                        break;
                    case "department":
                        tableName = "setup_department";

                        break;
                }

                // error: data is a variable but is used as a type
                var col = db.GetCollection<data>(tableName);

                // error: data is a variable but is used as a type
                var records = data as BindingList<data>;

                col.Insert(records);

            }
        }
```

I'm doing something wrong here.  `T data` could be of type Models.SetupArea or Models.SetupDepartment or it can be anything actaully.

[image]

Any clue to fix it?

Comment: You should use `T` as generic type parameter instead of `data`

Comment: off-topic comment: does `T` is derived from `BindingList<T>` if not than this make no sens as `records` will always be null if so, why you didn't put right  constraint or making `data` `BindingList<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do:

```
var col = db.GetCollection<T>(tableName);
var records = data as BindingList<T>;
```

You need to put the type there, instead of variable.

Comment: Yes this is. you should use T instead data.